# How to get bit value of hex number based on position in python

Tags: python

Hi Friends I'm new person to Python language. I'm trying to write some small code which I want to integrate later in my python module. Here is my question

1. I have a number like `a[31:0]= 0X00010001` in a file and I want to get bit value based on position and do the operation based on its bit value. 
   I want to use something like common class across and I'm looking for solution if a number is more than 32 bits as well.
   `0x00010001.getbit(0) == 0` do some operation. Expecting if bit0 is 0 do operation.
2. One more I'm looking if I have corresponding mask bit how do I get value based on mask bit
   `0x00010001` in this case `bit[15]` is mask and `bit[0]` is value.

Appreciate help.

I have tried doing via bitstream module but was not successful

Answer (score 5):

For the first problem:

```
def getbit(x,n):
  "Get the n-th bit of the number x"
  return x & (1 << n) and 1 or 0
```

Explanation: `x & (1 << n)` means bitwise AND between `x` and `2^n`.
And the expression `P and 1 or 0` means: if `P` then return 1, otherwise return 0.

And this works for numbers of any size. Python is not limiting you to 32 bit integers.

Comment: `True and 1` returns 1

Comment: Correct. I fixed the post :-)

Comment: Thank you Levin I will try it out

Comment: `and` operator is defined as follows: `x and y` returns `x` is `x` is False, and `y` otherwise. `or` is defined as follows: `x or y` returns `y` if x is False, and `x` otherwise. So writing `p and 1 or 0` is like writing `p?1:0` in `C`.